# Is it possible to draw such a figure in latex using a tikz package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

- Desired image is similar to the following one:

[image]

- Code for image does not entirely related to showed image
- My problem is how to change showed code that will reproduce showed image

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{table try}
\author{Jof Frimpong}
\date{October 2022}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
    
\section{Introduction}
    
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \csvautotabular[]{latextry.csv}
\end{table}

    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    % \draw[](0,0) grid (5,5)
    \node[draw](a) at (0,0){Audit Fees};
    \node[draw](b) at (9,0){Profitability};
    \node[draw](c) [below of =a]{Audit Tenure};
    \node[draw](d) [below right of =b]{liquidity};
    \node[draw](e) [below  of =c]{firm size};
    \node[draw](f) at (0,-6){Board Size};
    \node[draw,fill=blue,text=white,shape=circle](g) at (5,0){\huge Audit Qualtiy};
    
    \draw[-latex](a) to (g);
    \draw[stealth-](c) to (g);
    \draw[line width=3pt][-{stealth [scale width=2]}](d) to (g);
    \draw[line width=3pt][-latex](f) to (g);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome! I can't understand what the question is. Could you please clarify?

Comment: What should show the picture? Please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` (which use your article) and end with `\end{document}`. Please, consider @rmano comment!

Comment: @zarko please I have done that

Comment: @rmano please is it ok now?

Comment: Sorry, no, I still don't know what the question is. You posted a code and no question (just the title, which I do not understand either... sorry)

Comment: You question is still very unclear. You ask in the title of your question whether it is possible to draw "such a figure" using Ti*k*Z and then you present the code of some kind of figure, which has been draw using Ti*k*Z. So, I wonder what you mean with "such a figure". Please provide an illustration or explanation of what you would like to achieve. Otherwise it is very hard to help you, considering the fact that even my crystal ball seems to be of no use here ... 

Comment: If I remove `\csvautotabular[]{latextry.csv}` (which we haven't) from your document example, I can compile it and get a drawn images. So it is not clear, what is your problem.

Comment: @Rmano,@Zarko,@Jasper Habicht, please think the wrong figure was attached, I have attached the correct figure for you to help.

Comment: Now your code is only vaguely related to the image.  Can you adjust the code to get closer to the image you want?  What parts of that image are you having trouble creating?  Surely you can change "Audit Quality" to become text, etc.

Comment: @Teepeemm  The lower aspect of it

Comment: Please edit your code to get the upper aspect of it.

Comment: @Teepeemm, ok, thanks, please then the lower part

Comment: I took a liberty in try to make your question more clear. If you not liked this, you can revert my editings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After painful pull-out what you after ... it seems, that you looking for the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,
                positioning,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 16mm,
  start chain = going below,
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, very thick, color=cyan},
    BC/.style args = {#1/#2}{decorate,
                decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
                pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
                post=moveto, post length=1pt,
                raise=#1, mirror},
                ultra thick,
                pen colour={#2}},
   BCL/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw=#1, rounded corners, 
                semithick, below=#2},      
     E/.style = {ellipse, draw=cyan, semithick, 
                 fill=cyan!30, font=\Large\bfseries},
     N/.style = {draw=cyan, semithick, minimum width = 8em, inner sep=1ex}
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={N, on chain}]
\node (a)   {text};
\node (b)   {text};
\node (c)   {text};
\node (d)   {text};
    \end{scope}
\node (e) [E, left= of {$(b.west)!0.5!(c.west)$}]  {TEXT};
%
\node (f) [N, left=of e.west |- a]   {text};
\node (g) [N, left=of e.west |- d]   {text};
%
    \foreach \i [count=\j]in {a,b,c,d, f,g}
{
\ifnum\j<5
    \draw[arr]   (\i.west) -- (e);
\else
    \draw[arr]   (\i.east) -- (e);
\fi
}
%
    \begin{scope}[nodes={BCL=orange/5mm}]
\draw[BC=3pt/orange]    (g.south west) 
                                -- node {text}
                        (g.south east);
\draw[BC=3pt/orange]    (e.west  |- d.south)
                                -- node {text}
                        (e.east  |- d.south);
\draw[BC=3pt/orange]    (d.south west)
                                -- node {text}
                         (d.south east);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**

- As I afraid, showed image in question is simplified ... final imager is different (again= :-)
- Desired images has on the left sides seven nodes and on the right sides five
- Thich changes can be simple accomplished with the following changes of the first version of answer:

  - defining two nodes chanis )L and R), one for the left side, and for right side
  - drawing first left chain, than middle node and finally right chain
  - it is still anticipated, that text in chains' nodes is one line and shorter or equal to `8em`
  - naming chain (`L` for the left side, `R` for the right side); by this is code a wee bit shorter and simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,
                positioning,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 16mm,
  start chain = L going below,      % added chain name, for leftside chain 
  start chain = R going below,      % new chain, for rightside 
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, very thick, color=cyan},
    BC/.style args = {#1/#2}{decorate,
                decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
                pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
                post=moveto, post length=1pt,
                raise=#1, mirror},
                ultra thick,
                pen colour={#2}},
   BCL/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw=#1, rounded corners, 
                semithick, font=\scshape, 
                align=center, below=#2},      
     E/.style = {ellipse, draw=cyan, semithick, 
                 fill=cyan!30, font=\Large\bfseries,
                 align=center},
     N/.style = {draw=cyan, semithick, minimum width = 8em, 
                 align=center, inner sep=1ex}
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={N, on chain=L}] % leftside chain of 7 nodes
\node   {text L1}; % node name: L-1
\node   {text L2};
\node   {text L3};
\node   {text L4};
\node   {text L5};
\node   {text L6};
\node   {text L7};
    \end{scope}
\node (e) [E, right= of L-4]  {TEXT\\ TEXT};
%
    \begin{scope}[nodes={N, on chain=R}] % rightside chain of 5 nodes
\node   [right=of L-2 -| e.east]
        {text R1}; % node name: R-1
\node   {text R2};
\node   {text R3};
\node   {text R4};
\node   {text R5};
    \end{scope}
%
\foreach \i in {1, 2,...,7}
    \draw[arr]   (L-\i.east) -- (e);
\foreach \i in {1, 2,...,5}
    \draw[arr]   (R-\i.west) -- (e);

%
    \begin{scope}[nodes={BCL=orange/5mm}]
\draw[BC=3pt/orange]    (L-7.south west) 
                                -- node {left side\\ nodes} 
                        (L-7.south east);
\draw[BC=3pt/orange]    (e.west  |- L-7.south)
                                -- node {text}
                        (e.east  |- L-7.south);
\draw[BC=3pt/orange]    (R-5.west |- L-7.south)
                                -- node {right side\\ nodes} 
                        (R-5.east |- L-7.south);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are good, Thank you very very much. it answers my problem. Once Again Thank you

Comment: Please I tried to edit your code to make the left nodes increase to seven squares and the right ones increase to five codes and the diagram changes. Please can you also help

Comment: @Joffrimpong, ih ,,, this means that in the left side you have 7 nodes, and on the right 5? This is simple to achieve with change order of drawing side nodes chains, I will write an addendum ASAP.

Comment: I am not all that good at latex but using it for my thesis, and I am highly impressed by you. Thank you very much

Comment: @Joffrimpong, thank you for nice word. When you will finished your thesis you will also mastered LaTeX ;-)

Comment: Please Sir, can you help with this:

Comment: Please Sir, thank you I have been able to edit your code and is helping me. Sir, I have posed another problem can you help? Thank you.