# How can I draw this type of hierarchy diagram in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please guide me in drawing this type of hierarchy diagram in Latex. [image]

### Update

I tried one of the proposed solutions. I have written this code for my graph. But the center nodes come in different sizes. Also, they are not aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,pifont,amssymb,yfonts, amsfonts, stmaryrd, pxfonts,eufrak, fancybox, bbm}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage[paperheight=20in,paperwidth=6in,margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{petri,decorations.markings}
\tikzstyle{process} = [auto, rectangle, minimum width=3em, minimum height=2em, text centered, draw=blue, fill=gray!10, rounded corners, node distance=4cm ]
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [ellipse, minimum width=2em, minimum height=2.5em, text centered, draw=blue, fill=red!10]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, minimum width=1em, minimum height=5em, text centered, draw= green, fill=green!10]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{line} = [ thick, color=black!150]
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Text orientation is wrong
                    \node (S) [block]{\rotatebox{90}{Selection of green supplier}};
%               \begin{scope}[node distance=2mm and 3mm]
                [
                    \node (S1) [process, above right=0.25cm and 3cm of S]{service and delivery $\left( {{\mathfrak{h}}_{5}}\right) $};
                    \node (S2) [process, below right=0.25cm and 3cm of S]{  the reputation of the supplier $\left( {{\mathfrak{h}}_{6}}\right) $};
                    \node (S3) [process, above =0.25cm and 3cm of S1]{operational and transportation cost $\left( {{\mathfrak{h}}_{4}}\right) $ };
                    \node (S4) [process, above =0.25cm and 3cm of S3]{supply chain flexibility $\left( {{\mathfrak{h}}_{3}}\right) $ };
                    \node (S5) [process, above =0.1cm and 3cm of S4]{quality $\left( {{\mathfrak{h}}_{2}}\right) $};
                    \node (S6) [process, above =0.1cm and 3cm of S5]{ Price $\left( {{\mathfrak{h}}_{1}}\right) $  };
                    \node (S7) [process, below =0.1cm and 3cm of S2]{green competencies $\left( {{\mathfrak{h}}_{7}}\right) $};
                    \node (S8) [process, below =0.1cm and 3cm of S7]{use of green packaging $\left( {{\mathfrak{h}}_{8}}\right) $};
                    \node (S9) [process, below =0.1cm and 3cm of S8]{environment management and control $\left( {{\mathfrak{h}}_{9}}\right) $};
                    \node (S10) [process, below =0.1cm and 3cm of S9]{use of eco-friendly technology $\left( {{\mathfrak{h}}_{10}}\right) $};
                    \node (S11) [cloud,  below right=1.9cm and 5cm of S1]{${\mathcal{P}_{1}}$ };
                    \node (S12) [cloud,   above=0.7cm and 5cm of S11]{${\mathcal{P}_{2}}$ };
                    \node (S13) [cloud,   above=0.7cm and 5cm of S12]{${\mathcal{P}_{3}}$ };
                    \node (S14) [cloud,   above=0.7cm and 5cm of S13]{${\mathcal{P}_{4}}$ };
                    \node (S15) [cloud,   below=0.7cm and 5cm of S11]{${\mathcal{P}_{5}}$ };
                      \node (S16) [cloud,   below=0.7cm and 5cm of S15]{${\mathcal{P}_{6}}$ };
                     \node (S17) [cloud,   below=0.7cm and 5cm of S16]{${\mathcal{P}_{7}}$ };
                    ]
%                   \end{scope}
                    \draw  (S) edge[->,out=0,in=180] (S1);
                    \draw (S) edge[->,out=0,in=180] (S2);
                    \draw (S) edge[->,out=0,in=180] (S3);
                    \draw (S) edge[->,out=0,in=180] (S4);
                    \draw (S) edge[->,out=0,in=180] (S5);
                    \draw  (S) edge[->,out=0,in=180] (S6);
                    \draw  (S) edge[->,out=0,in=180] (S7);
                    \draw (S) edge[->,out=0,in=180] (S8);
                    \draw  (S) edge[->,out=0,in=180] (S9);
                    \draw (S) edge[->,out=0,in=180] (S10);
                    \draw (S1) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S11);
                    \draw (S1) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S12);
                    \draw (S1) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S13);
                    \draw (S1) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S14);
                    \draw (S1) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S15);
                    \draw (S1) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S16);
                    \draw  (S1) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S17);
                    \draw (S2) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S11);
                    \draw (S2) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S12);
                    \draw (S2) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S13);
                    \draw (S2) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S14);
                    \draw  (S2) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S15);
                    \draw  (S2) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S16);
                    \draw  (S2) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S17);
                    \draw  (S3) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S11);
                    \draw (S3) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S12);
                    \draw (S3) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S13);
                    \draw  (S3) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S14);
                    \draw (S3) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S15);
                    \draw  (S3) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S16);
                    \draw (S3) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S17);
                    \draw (S4) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S11);
                    \draw  (S4) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S12);
                    \draw  (S4) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S13);
                    \draw  (S4) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S14);
                    \draw  (S4) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S15);
                    \draw  (S4) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S16);
                    \draw (S4) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S17);
                    \draw  (S5) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S11);
                    \draw  (S5) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S12);
                    \draw  (S5) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S13);
                    \draw  (S5) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S14);
                    \draw  (S5) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S15);
                    \draw (S5) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S16);
                    \draw (S5) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S17);
                    \draw (S6) edge[>->,out=0,in=180](S11);
                    \draw  (S6) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S12);
                    \draw  (S6) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S13);
                    \draw  (S6) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S14);
                    \draw  (S6) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S15);
                    \draw  (S6) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S16);
                    \draw  (S6) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S17);
                    \draw  (S7) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S11);
                    \draw  (S7) edge[>->,out=0,in=180](S12);
                    \draw  (S7) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S13);
                    \draw  (S7) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S14);
                    \draw  (S7) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S15);
                    \draw  (S7) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S16);
                    \draw  (S7) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S17);
                    \draw (S8) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S11);
                    \draw  (S8) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S12);
                    \draw  (S8) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S13);
                    \draw  (S8) edge[>->,out=0,in=180](S14);
                    \draw  (S8) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S15);
                    \draw (S8) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S16);
                    \draw  (S8) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S17);
                    \draw  (S9) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S11);
                    \draw  (S9) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S12);
                    \draw  (S9) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S13);
                    \draw  (S9) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S14);
                    \draw  (S9) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S15);
                    \draw  (S9) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S16);
                    \draw  (S9) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S17);
                    \draw  (S10) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S11);
                    \draw  (S10) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S12);
                    \draw (S10) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S13);
                    \draw  (S10) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S14);
                    \draw  (S10) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S15);
                    \draw  (S10) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S16);
                    \draw  (S10) edge[>->,out=0,in=180] (S17);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Here is not service "we-do-your-task-instead-of-you". You may see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661358/is-it-possible-to-draw-such-a-figure-in-latex-using-a-tikz-package/661387#661387 (addendum) and on this base try to construct desired picture.

Comment: I have written this code for my graph. But the center nodes come in different sizes.  Also, they are not aligned.

Comment: Where you write code for your graph? in your answer? Compilation result is nowhere near as drawn in the question. Please edit your question, and insert the code of what you try to id. Let code be minimal (drop out all what is not related to graph).

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your misalignments. Simplifies understanding your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear! What you is the problem?

- Recreate showed image?
- Clean-up and correcting code in your "answer" so that compilation result will be more similar to showed image in your question?
- So far the compilation of the document in your answer is not even close to showed image.

An example, how your code in "answer" can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=20in,paperwidth=6in,margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, eufrak}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains, 
                positioning}
                 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 22mm,
  start chain = A going below,
  start chain = B going below,
    N/.style = {draw=blue, fill=gray!20,
                text width=#1, align=flush center},
    C/.style = {circle, draw=blue, fill=red!20,
                minimum size=1.5em}
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={N=44mm, on chain=A}]
\node   {Price $(\mathfrak{h}_{1})$ };              % node name = A-1
\node   {quality $(\mathfrak{h}_{2})$};
\node   {supply chain flexibility $(\mathfrak{h}_{3})$};
\node   {operational and transportation cost $(\mathfrak{h}_{4})$};
\node   {service and delivery $(\mathfrak{h}_{5})$};
\node   {reputation and suplayer $(\mathfrak{h}_{6})$};
\node   {green competencies $(\mathfrak{h}_{7})$};
\node   {use of green packaging $(\mathfrak{h}_{8})$};
\node   {environment management and control $(\mathfrak{h}_{9})$};
\node   {use of eco-friendly technology $(\mathfrak{h}_{10}) $};
    \end{scope}
\node (S) [N=22mm, fill=orange!30, left=of A-6]   
        {Selection of green supplier};

    \begin{scope}[nodes={C, on chain=B}]
\node   [right=of {$(A-2.east)!0.5!(A-3.east)$}]   
        {${\mathcal{P}_{1}}$ };    % node name = B-1
\node   {${\mathcal{P}_{2}}$ };
\node   {${\mathcal{P}_{3}}$ };
\node   {${\mathcal{P}_{4}}$ };
\node   {${\mathcal{P}_{5}}$ };
\node   {${\mathcal{P}_{6}}$ };
\node   {${\mathcal{P}_{7}}$ };
     \end{scope}

\foreach    \i in {1,2,...,10}
    \draw   (S.east)  -- (A-\i.west);

\foreach    \i in {1,...,10}
{
\foreach    \j in {1,...,7}
    \draw   (A-\i.east) -- (B-\j.west);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is still not a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140722) (MMW). Here is a possible MWE for your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
myfill/.style={draw=teal,thick,top color=white, bottom color=cyan,align=center},    
Lbox/.style={myfill,minimum width=3.5cm,inner sep=5mm},
Cbox/.style={myfill,minimum width=4.8cm,minimum height=1.2cm},
Rbox/.style={myfill,minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=1.8cm}
}

\tikzset{declare function={a=6;b=.75;}} % for distances in center boxes
\path 
(0,0)    node[Lbox] (L) {Selection of the\\Renewable Energy \\Sources}
(a,b)    node[Cbox] (Water) {Water pollution}
(a,-b)   node[Cbox] (Pollutant) {Pollutant emission}
(a,3*b)  node[Cbox] (Operation) {Operation and maintenance\\cost}
(a,-3*b) node[Cbox] (Land) {Land requirement}
;

\tikzset{declare function={c=6;d=1.1;}} % for distances in right boxes
\path (Water)++(0,-.8)
+(c,d)    node[Rbox] (Wind) {Wind energy}
+(c,-d)   node[Rbox] (Hydropower) {Hydropower energy}
+(c,3*d)  node[Rbox] (Solar) {Solar energy}
+(c,-3*d) node[Rbox] (Biomass) {Biomass energy}
(Water.east)+(.6,0) coordinate (A)
;

\foreach \i in {Water,Pollutant,Operation,Land}
\draw[magenta] (L.east)--(\i.west) (A)|-(\i.east);
\foreach \i in {Solar,Wind,Hydropower,Biomass}
\draw[magenta] (A)--(\i.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Both types of graphs are fine for problem formulation. Now, I can modify them as per my requirement. One more question, both the graphs in horizontal. How can I rotate them in a vertical direction?

Comment: @RajkumarVerma the node option `rotate=90` does that job. Anyway, your questions are unclear, not descriptive. Please improve them to help the helpers ^^ Also learn how to use this texSE forum properly: how to upvote, how to accept an answer, what is a MWE, etc